# In den Bergen vs auf den Bergen

Tags: preposition, standard-german

What is the difference between **in** den Bergen and **auf** den Bergen? We say *in die Berge fahren* and *in den Bergen sein*. What about *auf die Berge*? Does it only refer to mountain climbing and getting to the very top?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Auf den Bergen (1)

literally means on top of/on some mountains, whereas

> In den Bergen   (2)

is denoting a mountaneous region.

**Examples:**

> (1) Auf dem Berg gibt es kein Gipfelkreuz.
>   (1) Auf den Berg klettern.
>   (1) Auf diesen Bergen gibt es kaum Bäume.
>   (2) Wir verbringen unseren Urlaub in den Bergen.
>   (2) Ich bin in den Bergen aufgewachsen.
>   (2) In den Bergen wandern gehen.

An exception would be:

> In den Bergen gibt es viel Salz.

On the other hand, a singular version of (2) can only refer to a mountain's *inside*.

Comment: Yes _im Berg_ certainly refers to something inside the mountain (like mining etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You would use "auf die Berge" to emphasize getting on the top of mountains - by foot, by bike, by cable car or by something else doesn't matter much.